# program to find the number of exchanges that will happen until k minutes are passed

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given n runners running on a circular track. each runner when cross another runner, they exchange gems. Given an array of the time taken (in minutes) by each runner to complete the circular track and an integer k. We need to find the number of exchanges that will happen until k minutes are passed.

[EDIT 1]: I thought along the lines of using hcf of all the numbers for meeting point, but could not get through. Any help would be nice.

Comment: what is hfc? How many runners are there? What is the limit of k?

Answer (score 1):

What we're trying to do here is to count the number of times a runner passes another runner. First of all, we can sort the runners by their speed, this will come in handy later. For the `i`th runner, we can easily compute the number of laps they will run, which I will refer to as `L(i)`. For two runners `i` and `j` where `i` is faster than `j`, the number of times `i` will pass `j` is `floor(L(i) - L(j))`. Our solution is the sum of this value for all of the pairs of `i` and `j` where `i > j`.

If the limit for `n` is small enough, you can just loop over all these pairs and sum up the values in `O(n^2)` time. But if `n` is large, this will be too slow. If we simply wanted to compute the sum of `L(i) - L(j)` for all of `i > j` without the floor function, we can do this in linear time using prefix sums.

If our runners are numbered from 0 to `n - 1` in the order of their speed, for each value of `i`, the sum of `L(i) - L(j)` for all values of `j` less than `i` is equal to `L(i) * i - P(i - 1))`, where `P(j)` is the precomputed value of the sum of `L(0) + L(1) + L(2) + ... + L(j)`. Now we need to deal with the floor function. For two real numbers `x` and `y` where `x > y`, `floor(x - y)` is equal to `floor(x) - floor(y)` if the fractional part of `x` is greater than or equal to the fractional part of `y`, and `floor(x) - floor(y) - 1` otherwise.

So if we need to compute the number of times a runner `i` pass another runner, we can first compute the value using the prefix sum technique described above with the floor of each `L` value and then subtract the number of `j` values where the fractional part of `L(j)` is greater than the fractional part of `L(i)`. Finding the number of `j` values with the fractional part of `L(j)` greater than the fractional part of `L(i)` is basically [inversion counting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-inversions-array-set-3-using-bit/) on real numbers, which can be done with a binary indexed tree.

The final complexity is `O(n log n)`.